# Swift define double pointer for struct defined in c

Tags: swift, pointers, struct

I have a library which contains this function:

```
void create_pointer(Pointer **pointer);
```

It takes a pointer's pointer and allocates memory for it. in c, I can do it like this

```
Pointer *pointer;
create_pointer(&pointer);
```

then I have a pointer's instance.

But now I want to use this function in Swift. How?

I have no details about Pointer, I only know it's a struct, defined like this

```
typedef struct Pointer Pointer;
```

Comment: None of this appears to be Objective-C related or coming from Apple's frameworks. Swift is a layer on top of the Objective-C runtime, so third-party libraries are not going to be directly compatible.

Comment: Quite no agreed, Swift is a layer on top of the Objective-C runtime, I think it has it's own runtime, and call across language is the most important feature of modern language.

Comment: Swift has components but they all tap into the existing Obj-C runtime. I agree with your point and would *love* to see Swift on other platforms but... that's not happening soon. To be fair, Apple has made the Obj-C runtime open source for a while now. It's just that the **frameworks** that others have built are not quite as good as Apple's offerings on Mac/iOS.

Comment: For me it seems there is no choice except implements the library I used again use swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with a C example

```
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger someNumber;
} SomeStruct;

void create_some_struct(SomeStruct **someStruct) {
    *someStruct = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct));
    (*someStruct)->someNumber = 20;
}
```

In C, you would use it like this:

```
//pointer to our struct, initially empty
SomeStruct *s = NULL;  

//calling the function
create_some_struct(&s);
```

In Swift:

```
//declaring a pointer is simple
var s: UnsafePointer<SomeStruct> = UnsafePointer<SomeStruct>.null()

//well, this seems to be almost the same thing :)
create_some_struct(&s)

println("Number: \(s.memory.someNumber)"); //prints 20
```

**Edit:**

If your pointer is an opaque type (e.g. `void *`), you have to use

```
var pointer: COpaquePointer = COpaquePointer.null()
```

Note that Swift is not designed to interact with C code easily. C code is mostly unsafe and Swift is designed for safety, that's why the Swift code is a bit complicated to write. Obj-C wrappers for C libraries make the task much easier.

Comment: I test your code, Xcode give me two error, first is 'withUnsafePointer': 'UnsafePointer<$T1>' is not a subtype of '()', second is 'someStruct.memory.someNumber': 'UnsafePointer<Pointer>?' does not have a member named 'memory'

Comment: @user3709449 I removed the `withUnsafePointer` part. It doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: after remove withUnsafePointer, Xcode give me this convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'inout UnsafePointer<Pointer>?', the second error is the same

Comment: @user3709449 That's because your struct is an opaque (unknown type).  See my edit.